# Select query where column does not equal column in different table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different tables that contain order/pricing data. The first table, `Orders`, has columns `order`, `item` and `price`. The second table, `Pricing` has columns `item`, `price`, and `effective date`. I want to find all orders where `orders.price` <> `pricing.price` where effective date = 7/27/2017.

**Orders**:

```
Order  Item    Price
---------------------
1      ABC     12.50
2      ABC     12.00
3      ABC     11.50
4      XYZ     20.00
```

**Pricing**:

```
Item    Price    Effective Date
-------------------------------
ABC     12.50    7/27/2017
ABC     12.00    12/1/2016
ABC     11.50    12/1/2015
XYZ     25.00    7/27/2017
XYZ     20.00    12/1/2016
```

I want the query to tell me that order 2,3,4 do not have the most up to date pricing.

Please advise.

Comment: First you need to write a query from the second table that shows you the most up to date price. What version of SQL Server? What have you tried so far

Comment: Thank you this is all I needed to get me in the right direction! Got it figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM Orders O
INNER JOIN Pricing P ON O.Item = P.Item
Where O.Price != P.Price AND [Effective Date] ='07/27/2017'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT O.ORDER, (P.PRICE - O.PRICE) AS 'Variance'
FROM ORDERS O, PRICING P
WHERE O.ITEM = P.ITEM
AND P.[EFFECTIVE DATE] = '7/27/2017'
AND P.PRICE <> O.PRICE
ORDER BY O.ORDER ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT o.[Order]
  FROM Orders o JOIN Pricing p
    ON o.Item = p.Item
   AND p.Effective_Date = '2017-07-27'
   AND o.price <> p.price
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20f05d3/1) demo

Output:

```
| Order |
|-------|
|     2 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.order,o.Item,o.price from orders o inner join
pricing on o.item=pricing.item 
where o.price <>(select p.price from pricing p where p.effectivedate = '2017-07-27' and p.item=o.item)
```